# Issue in running java 17 based project in eclipse 2019-12

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

currently i getting an exception while trying to run an opensource project

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: ghidra.GhidraClassLoader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(java.base@17.0.6/ClassLoader.java:1995)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase3(java.base@17.0.6/System.java:2246)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ghidra.GhidraClassLoader
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@17.0.6/BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@17.0.6/ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@17.0.6/ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@17.0.6/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@17.0.6/Class.java:467)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(java.base@17.0.6/ClassLoader.java:1981)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase3(java.base@17.0.6/System.java:2246)
```

My eclipse version is 2019-12
java version needed for the project java 17

gradle version needed is 7.3+ and my is 7.5

these commands specified in their page works in command line and the build was successfull.

```
gradle -I gradle/support/fetchDependencies.gradle init
gradle prepdev eclipse buildNatives
```

Inside eclipse

```
The import java.awt cannot be resolved
```

for

```
import java.awt.AWTError;
```

these errors are showing for all sub projects and all imported java libraries and under class names.

[image]

these exclamatory marks are present for each nested projects.

And also i have installed java 17
[image]

Comment: FYI, I found this Javadoc for [`GhidraClassLoader`](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/GhidraClassLoader.html).

Comment: i am trying to run the entire Ghidra source code through eclipse but is not working where should i start

Comment: You should start by carefully reading any build instructions ... etcetera.

Comment: the build was successful in the terminal

Comment: but i want to run it in eclipse and debug the source code

Comment: Java 17 didn't exist until 2021. Do not expect a version of Eclipse older than that to work with it properly. Eclipse releases quarterly, making the current release 2023-03. Try that one.

Comment: is it possible to maintain 2 different versions of eclipse in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the comments i tried installing the eclipse 2023-03 in a different folder Along with the older version. Then re cloned the entire project and initialized the build instruction provided in the page. After that i was able to run the project properly.

It was little confusing for people who are new to programming and the IDE version was not specified.